# [problema al imprimir una jTable en java >8 y de escalado en java 8

Tags: java, java-8, jtable, imprimir, java-9

Siguiendo [este codigo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html) Cuando imprimo un JTable con java 9 u 11 si he movido la barra de scrool, la impresión(en pdf) el borde de la tabla llega hasta la ultima+1 fila, si lo hago en java 8, se soluciona el problema pero el tamaño de los frames sale pequeño(tengo una pantalla 4k).
como puede corregir la escala o el problema del borde?

Antes de imprimir en java 8
[image: Antes de imprimir en java 8]

Pdf de java 8

[image: pdf]]

Antes de imprimir en java 9

[image: Antes de imprimir en java 9]

pdf en java 9

[image: pdf en java 9]

También si dejo el scroll todo abajo, en la impresión solo sale la primera pagina.
La impresión la intente con el metodo print de la tabla con o sin parametros, y con un PrinterJob

```
    PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, (float) pf.getWidth() , (float) pf.getHeight(),
            MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    job.setPrintable(table.getPrintable(null, null, null), pf);
    if (job.printDialog()) {
        try {
            job.print(aset);
        } catch (PrinterException pe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(pe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Según lo que he leído en Java 8 hay un bug que le dice a Windows que es consiente del DPI de la pantalla  y no escala, debes de utilizar java 9 o superior que ya tiene corregido esto, o agregar este parámetro al ejecutar tu programa `-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false` aunque según este post https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display tuvo que modificar el `exe de java` para que funcionara en java 8.

Comment: El problema con java 9 o superior es que si hago scroll en la impresión sale ese borde. por el momento lo que hice fue hacer que antes de imprimir dejara el scroll hacia arriba